# execute a command via shortcut in i3

Tags: terminal, i3

my goal is to be able to press a Key combination and it opens a terminal in a specific workspace (in i3) executing a command. (i already have it in aliases but i use this command very often)

I hope i can do this via the i3 config I know that you can force applications to open in specific workspaces, but all i want to open is a normal terminal and obviously i don't wont my all my terminals to open in this Workspace

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many terminal emulators have an option to specify the name of the class, instance or title of a newly created window. This must be a unique name.

i3 can act on any window with the directive `for_window` using any of those attributes.

For example, to open an Alacritty terminal executing `cal` with the class name `myterm` on workspace 6 and switching to it, add to your config:

```
for_window [class="myterm"] move container to workspace 6
bindsym $mod+Control+6 exec "alacritty --class 'myterm,myterm' --hold -e cal"; workspace 6
```

With xterm:

```
bindsym $mod+Control+6 exec "xterm -class myterm -hold -e cal"; workspace 6
```

A "hold" option is usually required to keep the window from immediately closing after executing a command.

Check the manpage of your specific terminal emulator for the relevant options.

Comment: thank you for this quick respond i added "bindsym $mod+Control+6 exec "kitty --class 'kitty,kitty' --hold -e cal"; workspace 6", but this forces every terminal to open in workspace 6 and it doesn't automaticly execute a command when i start it. ^This is not a solution to my answer^

Comment: @fabolous05 the default class name for all `kitty` windows is already `kitty` so i3 will act on all `kitty` windows. The name of the class / instance / title needs to be unique and not the same as what is assigned by the program. You can check the window class / instance name with `xprop`, which is assigned to `WM_CLASS(STRING)`.

Comment: @fabolous05 according to the [manpage](https://man.archlinux.org/man/kitty.1) for `kitty`, only the class name should be specified: `kitty --class <class>`.  `--class <instance>,<general>` only applies to `alacritty`. `kitty` also does not use an `-e` option to specify the command to run. It should just be the last argument of the command line. Example: `kitty --class myclass --hold cal`

Comment: Thank you this helped so far but i noticed that i can't add aliases to the config. I tried ll which is ubuntu standard alias for "ls -l" and it didn't worked (I had to switch workspace 7; and the execute command to open kitty in ws7). With an alias in my conf I can see kitty open in ws7 for half a second and then closin automaticly i tried to read the error message:

"Traceback most recent call:
(something with:)File: /usr/bin/.../lib/kitty __main__.py line 33"

There is much more but i think thats the most important stuff

Comment: @fabolous05 aliases won't work if you execute a command directly with a terminal because aliases require an interactive shell. Your binding should set the terminal to run an interactive shell and from there you can use an alias. Example: `kitty --class myclass --hold bash -i -c ll`

Comment: Thank you this fixed my problem

Comment: @fabolous05 you're welcome, glad it worked out. Please consider accepting my answer if it was helpful. Thanks.